# prism mvvmlight view activation error, exception occurred while trying to create an instance of viewmodel

Tags: wpf, prism, mvvm-light

The solution worked perfectly using Prism only.

However, after I use Nuget to install MVVMLight, the view can no longer be activated. The RootCauses in the exception snapshot is about create an instance of the type of my viewmodel.

The source is about the Microsoft.Practice.ServiceLocation

I have uninstalled both Prism and MVVMLight, then reinstall them. But still not working.

Uninstall MVVMLight seems get the solution working again.

Comment: Why do you want both MVVMLight & PRISM? Do you need them both?

Comment: I need the modularity from Prism and eventTocommand with eventarg from mvvmlight.

By using the full installation (not the mvvmlight libraries only) i get it working. also remove the app.xaml viewmodel locator will also help.